How to limit to 1 node per user?
I have a website with Drupal 11 and the Rules 4 module.
I created a content type "profile".
The authenticated user can currently create a node of type "profile".
My problem is that when the user has created his node, I want that when he accesses the node creation form, it is an access denied and a message indicates that he has reached the limit (1 node per user).
How to limit the creation of 1 node per user, for a specific content type ?
The Rules module is extremely poorly documented and complex to take in hand.

For what it's worth https://www.drupal.org/project/eca is more prevalent than rules in new Drupal versions.

You may be able to do this with the Entity Limit module.  Also, if you are coding this yourself, if the user has reached the limit, instead of giving an "access denied" on the create entity page, I would redirect the user to the node that has already been created.

@PatrickKenny Thanks but this module does not work with drupal 11. I am not comfortable with the code, maybe ECA is a good idea. Hoping it does not take a bad path like Rules

@PatrickKenny It's a very good idea to redirect to his profile with a message

@monalisa I am looking at ECA can you explain in a response the sub-modules to activate and how to limit the creation of nodes per user? 1 profile type node per user, if he tries to access the form or the node creation path, he is redirected to his first node and a message is displayed (Limit reached). Thank you

The solution is with how you think about your workflow.
Create a role that has permission to create a 'profile'. Users who are allowed to create a profile should be given that role, for example when they create an account. Once a user has created a profile, remove that role from the user.
This can easily be done with Rules. The Rule to give the user the ability to create a profile would be:
Event: After saving a new user entity
Action: Add user role

(you could also add a Condition to this if you wanted to restrict which new users were allowed to create a profile)
And the Rule to remove that ability would be:
Event: After saving a new profile entity
Action: Remove user role

You can also make another Rule if you want to restore the role if the profile was deleted, for example.
Event: After deleting a profile entity
Action: Add user role

In all cases, when you Add a reaction rule, it is extremely helpful to add tags and a description of the rule right from the start, especially when you are creating several rules like that which all participate in the same workflow. The tags and descriptions are searchable in the Rules overview page, and adding this information up front will make things a lot easier in the long run.

you can use the following custom code in a custom module.
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

    /**
     * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
     */
    function mymodule_form_node_profile_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
      $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
      $query->condition('type', 'profile');
      $query->condition('uid', $current_user->id());
      $result = $query->execute();
    
      if (!empty($result)) {
        \Drupal::messenger()->addError('You can only create one profile.');
        $form['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }

This hook modifies the "profile" node creation form. If the user already has a profile node, it blocks access and shows an error message. You can replace the mymodule with your module name and node_profile_form with your form id

Please note that depending the context, this approach may be not robust enough: it blocks the creation on the form, but it doesn't check any other method - e.g. JSON:API. If those are case to be considered, it would be better to use hook_entity_create_access as entity limit module does or maybe an entity constraint, to block the profile creation in any possible context.

how to do this with Rules or ECA ?
